# Trying to link JQuery Mobile into html. Works when using a hosted version, but not local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've been having issue linking in the JQuery api into my html page. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out myself, but haven't made any progress, and would really appreciate anyone's help! Like I mentioned in the title, it works fine when I link to a hosted version of JQuery, but when I try to use a local version, I have no success (I need to work locally for what I'm using it for). Side Note: I downloaded the files directly from JQuery's site, and put them in the root folder for simplicity.

Please see the code below...

**This does not work properly:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
```

**But this does work properly:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  

</body>
```

Comment: Load jquery mobile after jquery, like you did in the second sinppet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the order the scripts are coming in - your working version has jQuery first, then mobile, while the non-working one has the opposite. If that doesn't fix it, double-check that your file paths are all correct - the way it's written, your html file must be in the same folder as the scripts. If it's not, try prepending a slash: `<script src="/jquery-2.2.3.js">` to force it to look at the root folder.

One way to confirm whether that's the issue is to check your browser dev tools. If you're in chrome, right click -> inspect element, and find the Network tab. Reload your page while you've got that open and see if your page is successfully loading the scripts. If you see the names of those scripts in red, it means they weren't found or couldn't be loaded.

Last thought: if you're working on your local site via opening a `file://` path, the JS you can use will be restricted; this is a security feature. To get around it, run your site on a local server. Mac OS X has a built-in one, or you can use PHP or python to get one up and running immediately from the command line, or install a library like `pow` or `serve`. Google around for 'local web server setup', there are tons of options.